# Case when to find the difference in the number of counts of particular kind of rows.

Tags: sql

I have a **table** which looks like this

```
col1, col2
a,C
a,D
a,C
a,D
```

I want to find out that for **a** in `col1`, what is the (Number of rows with **C** - Number of rows with **D**).

If I were to find the two numbers it will simply be

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mytable where COL1='a' and COL2='C'
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mytable where COL1='a' and COL2='D'
```

And then I could just find the difference.

However, I wanted to do it with a single query. So I went for this

```
SELECT COUNT(CASEWHEN(COL2)='D', 1, -1) 
FROM mytable
```

But that does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks folks for the quick responses. For me, the following code snippet worked.

```
SUM( CASEWHEN (COL2='D', 1, -1))
```

And a slightly fuller version of this is

```
SUM( CASE WHEN COL2='C' THEN -1 WHEN  COL2='D' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END)
```

I would recommend the fuller version.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Col2C,
        SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Col2D,
        SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'C' THEN 1 WHEN col2 = 'D' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) [Col2C-Col2D]
FROM myTable
WHERE col1 = 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'C' THEN 1 WHEN col2 = 'D' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) as Diff
from mytable
where col1 = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN COL2='D' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) as balance
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, this should work:

```
SELECT col1, SUM(CASE WHEN COL2 ='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN COL2 ='D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY col1
```